# Print all List elements in C

Tags: c

i build this interface for List in c,i insert to the list pointer of array of struct,
now i want to print all the fields of the struct,how can i do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct element {
    void *item;
    struct element *next;
} Element;

typedef Element* position;
typedef Element* List;

typedef struct strc   
{
    int row,col,value;
} Strc;

List initList()  
{
    Element *ls=malloc(sizeof(Element));
    if(ls)
        ls->next=NULL;
    else
        ls=NULL;
    return ls;
}

position insertToList(position p, void *item)  
{
    position newp=malloc(sizeof(Element));
    if(newp)
    {
        newp->next=p->next;
        p->next=newp;
        newp->item=item;
        //p=p->next;
    }
    else newp=NULL;
    return newp;
}

void *retriveFromList(position p)  {    return p->item;    }

position Next(position p)  {    return (position)p->next;    }

int isEmpty(List ls)  {    return ls->next==NULL;    }  

void freeList(List ls)  
{
    position pos=ls->next;
    while(ls->next!=NULL)
    {
        pos=ls->next;
        ls->next=pos->next;
        free(pos);
    }
}
void puts(List *ls)
{
    Position p=*ls;
    Strc *tmp;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        tmp=(Strc *)malloc(sizeof(strc));
        tmp->row=i;
        tmp->col=i+1;
        tmp->value=i+2;
        p=insertToList(p,tmp);
    }
}
void print_list(List ls)  
{
    position p=ls->next;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%3d\n",*((int*) retriveFromList(p)));
        p=Next(p);          
    }
}

void main()
{
    List ls=initList();
    puts(&ls);
    print(ls);
}
```

Comment: Who wrote this code ? (Yes I am implying you didn't write it)

Comment: And how many decades ago was that?

Comment: @cnicutar, what signals that this code is old to you? (Genuinely curious, not doubting or trying to pick a fight).

Comment: @KyleWpppd I did not say it was old. I said it was written by somebody else because **the OP doesn't know how to use it**.

Comment: @KyleWpppd including conio.h for no good reason (as a "standard header that we always include") went out of fashion many moons ago.

Comment: My teacher wrote the list interface.

Comment: @cnicutar, my apologies, I mentally combined the two comments into one. So, with my C being rather shabby, it looks like the op is calling `print` when `print_list` is needed, and needs to rename  `puts`.

Comment: @KyleWpppd No problem. I your suggestion is correct, it should work :-)

Comment: Uhhh, doesn't this already print out the contents of the list?

Comment: it's print only the row field,i want print all the struct fields

Comment: And after all we're still just leakin' along.

Comment: @WTP, where's the memory leak?

Comment: @Bodipo even if it is not an issue, and especially because you are still learning (as you mentioned you have a teacher), it's good practice to always free dynamically allocated memory if you don't need it anymore (to prevent you from forgetting this when doing real work).

Comment: @KyleWpppd in the `main` function. `freeList` isn't being called. You shouldn't depend on the OS freeing this for you when the program terminates. Also, something I just noticed: `tmp=(Strc *)malloc(sizeof(strc));
        tmp->row=i;` will crash if `malloc` fails (null dereference). :)

Comment: I agree with you,but i posted this code to try understanding how can i print all the fields of the struct which is in the list.

Comment: @Bodipo, I think this is the wrong approach. As someone who is learning myself: take the time to make sure all of the code is correct. You can't skip corners in learning to do things the right way. It will always come back to you.

Comment: @WTP, I edited my answer to check for the null dereference, but honestly the way it is would anger me if I had to work on it. Mostly because we run `malloc(sizeof(x))` 10 times rather than `malloc(10*sizeof(x))`, but I'm not sure if that's being nitpicky. I'm usually in scripting languages where something like that isn't a concern.

Answer (score 1):

### So, my C isn't grand

But, it seems like there are a ton of little typos that are going to eat you as you get this to run. One of the biggest being that `puts()` is already defined in `stdio.h`.

First, this thing doesn't compile for me, so working through all the compiler errors got me pretty far. Your `puts` function also was missing a closing bracket. I renamed it to `putv()` and changed it to be the following.

```
void putv(List *ls)
{
  position p=*ls;
  Strc *tmp;
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
      if(tmp=(Strc *)malloc(sizeof(Strc)))
        { 
          tmp->row=i;
          tmp->col=i+1;
          tmp->value=i+2;
          p=insertToList(p,tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

The second issue was that your main function was not calling `print_list()`, but instead calling plain `print()`.

```
void main()
{
  List ls=initList();
  putv(&ls);
  print_list(ls);
}
```

#### This doesn't solve all of your problems

Mostly because I don't think it's printing **what** you want, but I'm going to leave a little bit for you to figure out.

Comment: Why `(List *ls)`? List is already a pointer, and you are not writing to `ls`, so I would do: `void putv(List ls) {` etc.

Comment: This is true. So to verify, mostly so I know I understand fully... 

The correct solution would also mean that in main, we call putv with `putv(ls)` rather than what is there now, `putv(&ls)`? And the existing way passes the address of the pointer ls into putv. Instead we can just pass ls, which is a pointer to a `List`, and operate on that list element directly. Which means we also also must change putv to have `position p=ls;`, and with insertToList use `(&p, tmp)` as our passed values.